# R find number of rows in a group and plot

Tags: r

I have a table of Tennis matches. I want to group by winner_ids and plot them against height, basically to check if the taller players have won more matches.
The data looks like this.

```
 m_id winner_id winner_height
    1         21    166
    2         21    166
    3         22    167
    4         21    166
    5         23    170
    6         24    163
    7         22    167
    8         25    164
```

Here m_id is the match_id. I want to plot number of matches a person has won against his height

example: 21 has won 3 matches and her height is 166 cm

how can I acheive this in ggplot?

my following code doesn't seem to be working

```
matches %>% group_by(winner_id) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = winner_ht, y = nrow((winner_id)))) + geom_point()
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(winner_id, winner_height) %>%
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    ggplot(aes(winner_height, n, label = winner_id)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_text(position = position_nudge(y = -0.1))
```

[image]

Explanation: We count the number of games `n` per `winner_id` and `winner_height` and pass the summarised data to `ggplot` where we plot `winner_height` vs. `n`. We can also add labels to indicate the `winner_id`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "m_id winner_id winner_height
    1         21    166
    2         21    166
    3         22    167
    4         21    166
    5         23    170
    6         24    163
    7         22    167
    8         25    164", header = T)
```